# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"

Tags: java, javafx, исключения

Есть окно, там находятся две кнопки, одна **Войти**, другая **Регистрация**, по нажатию любой из них у меня открывается новое свое окно, проблема именно с **Регистрация**, т.к. кнопка **Войти** отрабатывается исправно, а при нажатии на ***Регистрация* - выдает вот такое исключение:

> ```
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
>   at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
>   at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
>   at sample.Controller.lambda$registration$1(Controller.java:60)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>   at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>   at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
>   at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
>   at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
>   at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>   at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>   at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>   at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
>   at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
>   at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
>   at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
> ```
>
> `Method)  at`
>   `javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)`
>   `at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)`

Оно ссылается на контроллер и такую строку `loader.load();`. 
Как я понял это происходит из-за того, что не создается нужное окно, исправить сам это не смог. В чем же причина?

Вот сам контроллер:

```
public void enter () {
        authorizationButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        Stage newStage = new Stage();
            Parent root = null;
            try {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("chat.fxml"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            newStage.setTitle("GMMM v 1.0");
        newStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        newStage.setResizable(false);
        newStage.show();
            });
    }

    public void registration () {
        loginSignUpButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            loginSignUpButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("registration.fxml"));

            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();
        });
    }
```

Для примера сами FXML файлы я так понимаю не нужны?

Comment: Как будто нет файла chat.fxml, проверьте, что он правильно написан, в той же папке что и второй с регистрацией

Comment: Как я помню, если локейшн передавать в конструкторе, то проблемы такой не будет. Не помню почему так, но попробуйте

Comment: chat довольно опасное слово, оно может легко начинаться с русской "с" и только компилятор сможет отличить ее от "c". Я бы проверил это.